# Two PHP installs on one machine?

Tags: php

I think I have two PHP installs on my machine. if I run the following command:

```
which php
```

my system locates an install at **/usr/bin/php**. But the php I was using before reconfiguring was running from **/usr/local/zend/bin/php**

The problem is, I need to run the php in the **/usr/local/zend/bin** directory, but it looks like the other php is currently running. I tried to find the process and kill it using:

```
ps -ef | grep php
```

But it's not listed. My question is how can I specify which version of PHP should be running on my system (CentOS)?

Comment: you could uninstall one of them

Comment: Call phpinfo() and see the information. You may run a different php.exe if you run php from your command shell than your apache(?) does.

Comment: php.exe in `/usr/local/zend/bin/php`? Blasphemy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not a running process, so you won't find it with `ps`.  If you're using it on a web server, it'll usually be loaded as a module within your web server, such as Apache.  The binaries you're finding in `/usr/bin/php` and `/usr/local/zend/bin/php` are the CLI binaries, so you wouldn't use these with your website anyway.

The version that you're using is going to be the version of the library referenced by your web server.  If you're using Apache, you'll want to check Apache's configuration to see which library it points to.

You can also create a small script with `<? phpinfo(); ?>` in it, then load this from a web page to get detailed information about the version you're running.

Comment: Thanks! it turns out, when I reconfigured php, it dropped a php.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d, so apache was trying to load multiple php5 modules